# Why does std::numeric_limits<long long>::max() fail?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015, stl, max

This line of code fails to compile in VS2015 Update 3:

```
auto a = std::numeric_limits<long long>::max();
```

It cannot find the definition of `max()`. Why is this?

Comment: What is the full error message?  Did you `#include <limits>`?

Comment: Please post the error message. Do you have `<windows.h>` with its evil `min()` and `max()` macros included, by any chance?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That `max` call may interfere with "evil" `max` **preprocessor** macro defined in the Windows SDK headers, that you have probably included (directly or indirectly).

An option is to prevent the preprocessor `max` macro to kick in, using an **additional pair of parentheses**:

```
... = (std::numeric_limits<long long>::max)();
```

---

As an additional option, you may consider **`#define #NOMINMAX`** *before* including Windows headers. This will prevent the definition of the aforementioned `min` and `max` preprocessor macros.

However, note that some Windows headers (like the GDI+ ones) *do require* the Win32's `min` and `max` preprocessor macros, so in such cases the use of an additional pair of parentheses may be a better option.

Comment: This works. What is the syntax of this additional brackets? Is it C++ standard?

Comment: Another way would be to `#undef max` after including the windows headers.

Comment: @Sheen: Yes, it's standard C++. Those additional parens prevent the preprocessor `max` macro to kick in, which sounds like the cause of your error.

Comment: By far the best option is to `#define NOMINMAX` before incuding any Windows-related headers, or even add the define to your compiler command line. This is the documented way of preventing the Windows headers from defining `min` and `max`.