# SFINAE with numeric_limits<T>::max() on MSVC2017

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sfinae, enable-if, numeric-limits

The following code:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::numeric_limits<T>::max() == std::numeric_limits<U>::max(),
    bool>::type
same_max() {
    return true;
}

template <typename T, typename U>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::numeric_limits<T>::max() != std::numeric_limits<U>::max(),
    bool>::type
same_max() {
    return false;
}
```

doesn't compile on MSVC2017 (OK on gcc/clang), with the following error:

```
error C2995: 'std::enable_if<,bool>::type same_max(void)': function template has already been defined
```

Is this a problem with my SFINAE, or is this a bug in MSVC?

Note: using `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed` (or `std::is_signed<T>::value` ) instead of `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` compiles fine:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_signed<T>::value == std::is_signed<U>::value,
    bool>::type
same_signedness() {
    return true;
}

template <typename T, typename U>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_signed<T>::value != std::is_signed<U>::value,
    bool>::type
same_signedness() {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a MSVC bug (as usual :P).

Comment: The code looks correct.

Comment: Are both `operator==` and `operator!=` between those two types defined?

Comment: `#define NOMINMAX`?

Comment: @Jarod42 That sounds like the answer, making this question a possible dupe of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416418/define-nominmax-using-stdmin-max or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40492414/why-does-stdnumeric-limitslong-longmax-fail

Comment: @Jarod42, no. That's not a problem here. If you replace `max` with, e.g. `epsilon`, it won't work either.

Comment: @Bob__ `operator==` and `!=` are defined for all types which are supported by `numeric_limits`, via implicit type conversions, so that's not a problem here.

Comment: @Jarod42 I should have indeed mentioned that I already ruled out this problem via #undef max. I've been bitten by this before, so it's good to have it in comments for future readers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This definitely looks like a bug in the compiler. It doesn't accept member functions in SFINAE (note that the code in the question fails not only for `min()`/`max()`, but for any member function like `epsilon()` or `lowest()`), but it does accept member constants. You can use the following simple workaround with an additional level of indirection using `struct` (if limited to C++11):

```
template<typename T>
struct get_max {
    static constexpr T value = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
};

template <typename T, typename U>
typename std::enable_if<get_max<T>::value == get_max<U>::value, bool>::type
same_max() {
    return true;
}

template <typename T, typename U>
typename std::enable_if<get_max<T>::value != get_max<U>::value, bool>::type
same_max() {
    return false;
}
```

or a variable template (since C++14):

```
template<typename T>
inline constexpr T get_max_v = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();

template <typename T, typename U>
std::enable_if_t<get_max_v<T> == get_max_v<U>, bool>
same_max() {
    return true;
}

template <typename T, typename U>
std::enable_if_t<get_max_v<T> != get_max_v<U>, bool>
same_max() {
    return false;
}
```

To avoid potential problems with `min`/`max` macros defined in some headers (like `windef.h`), the function name can be parenthesized:

```
... = (std::numeric_limits<T>::max)();
```

Comment: Thanks for the bug confirmation and workarounds, they work great! Note for future readers: variable templates is C++14, so you must use the first workaround if you are limited to C++11.

Comment: @BorisDalstein, thanks for the note! I added into the answer.

Comment: I reported the bug here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/885683/sfinae-error-with-member-function-of-class-templat.html

Comment: This is obviously subjective, but I'm not sure we should encourage using the `_v` suffix for user-defined variable templates. Which one looks more readable: `int x = get_max<int>;` or `int x = get_max_v<int>;`? The suffix does make it consistent with many existing traits in the standard, but I believe the reason the standard is littered with these suffixes is that they had no choice (by C++14 the non-suffixed name was already taken). By the way, speaking of conciseness, you may also want to use `enable_if_t` for the C++14 version.

Comment: Oh, and since we're nitpicking, I believe that `static` is redundant with `constexpr` in the variable template version (static at global/namespace scope). You do need it though in the struct template (static at class scope: means something different).

Comment: @BorisDalstein, personally, I don't like these `_v` suffixes, too.

Comment: @BorisDalstein, it should be `inline`, not `static`. Thanks!